# em-http-request - Where do I put my EventMachine.stop?

Tags: ruby, http, eventmachine

I want to iterate over a JSON-API every 10th second, and do a second HTTP-request using the same connection (keepalive) if a certain key was found in the JSON-data. If I do not place  `EM.stop` in my code, the program stops to wait after finishing processing in req1.callback.

If I put `EM.stop` inside `req2.callback` it works and is iterating as expected.

But if the JSON-document did not include the key `foobar`, the program stops to wait after finishing processing in req1.callback.

If I add `EM.stop` in the last line inside req1.callback, req2.callback is aborted if the JSON-document had the key `foobar`.

How should I properly place `EM.stop` to make it iterate if the JSON-document had what I wanted or not?

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'

loop do    
  EM.run do
    c = EM::HttpRequest.new 'http://api.example.com/'

    req1 = c.get :keepalive => true
    req1.callback do
      document = JSON.parse req1.response
      if document.has_key? foobar   
        req2 = c.get :path => '/data/'
        req2.callback do
          puts [:success, 2, req2]
          puts "\n\n\n"
          EM.stop
        end
      end
    end
  end

  sleep 10
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a timer, you should use the actual timer support from EM: http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine.html#M000467

For example:

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'

EM.run do
  c = EM::HttpRequest.new 'http://google.com/'
  EM.add_periodic_timer(10) do
    # Your logic to be run every 10 seconds goes here!
  end
end
```

This way, you keep EventMachine running the whole time, instead of having to start/stop it every 10 seconds.

Comment: Perfect solution for me! Makes more sense to use this built-in functionality than to "hack" it around with an infinite loop and sleep.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'

loop do    
  EM.run do
    c = EM::HttpRequest.new 'http://google.com/'

    req1 = c.get :keepalive => true
    req1.callback do
      begin
        document = JSON.parse req1.response
        if document.has_key? foobar   
          req2 = c.get :path => '/data/'
          req2.callback do
            puts [:success, 2, req2]
            puts "\n\n\n"
            EM.stop
          end
        end
      rescue => e
        EM.stop
        raise e
      end
    end
    req1.errback do
      print "ERROR"
      EM.stop
    end
  end

  sleep 10
end
```

Comment: Just tried this, but it never seems to get inside `req1.callback`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks! I will try this before I accept the best suited answer.